# Why don't I see the option Suppress Embedded Field Blank Lines in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 V 13.0.4 SP4
VS 2010 Profesional SP1

This is my first time working with CR.  I have a report that may have two optional lines in a section. To supress the blank lines I saw in help and all over the Internet that you follow these steps.

1. Right click the field of interest and select Format object.
2. On the common tab check the box next to `Suppress Embedded Field Blank Lines`.

Seems easy, but I don't have that as an option.
I see `Supress` and `Suppress If Duplicated`. There looks to be enough space below the second to hold my desired option.  I've tried other fields and other reports still MIA.

Oddly enough I found no other posts anywhere with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too came across this problem and discovered this workaround (Using CR XI R2)

1) Right click the section on which you have blank fields to suppress and click "Section Expert"

2) Check "Suppress (No Drill-Down)" and click on the Small Icon next to it to open the Formula Editor.

3) Type the following code
**if {*Condition resulting in a blank record*} then true else false**

4) Click "Save and Close" and Click OK.

Comment: Just saw your answer. I don't have that project available to me right now, but I'll be doing reports on a new one later this week and I'll test this out. It looks promising.